# How can I make jodit textarea dynamic without using useMemo

Tags: reactjs, jodit

I made a text editor with jodit-react. but as soon as I enter a value in the text input, the focus is disabled.

```
{contentFromApi && (
    <JoditEditor
       value={contentFromApi}
       config={config}
       onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
    />
)}
```

I have the problem I mentioned when I do it this way.

**Functions:**

```
const handleTextAreaChange = (newTextAreaValue) => {
    setContentFromApi(newTextAreaValue);
};
```

**State and Fetch**

```
const { data, error } = useSWR('..');

const [contentFromApi, setContentFromApi] = useState();
```

**What I've tried:**

```
{React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
        <JoditEditor
             value={contentFromApi}
             config={config}
             onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
        />
    );
}, [])}
```

If I do it this way, the 'contentFromApi' data is not placed in the text editor because it comes from the api. If I force the codes to wait for the data to come from the api, I get the 'too many render' error by React.

What I want is, when the component is rendered for the first time, the text data from the api appears in the text editor and the change can be made in a healthy way. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer your question. But Other's can get help. In case your problem was not solved, Just initialize the config inside `useMemo`:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useMemo} from 'react';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const Example = ({placeholder}) => {
    const editor = useRef(null)
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')
    
const config = useMemo(
    () => ({
        readonly: false, 
    }),
    []
);
    return (
            <JoditEditor
                ref={editor}
                value={content}
                config={config}
                onChange={newContent => {setContent(newContent)}}
            />
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const [contentFromApi, setContentFromApi] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setContentFromApi("DATA FROM API");
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const handleTextAreaChange = (newTextAreaValue) => {
    setContentFromApi(newTextAreaValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      test:
      <input
        disabled={contentFromApi.length === 0}
        onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
        value={contentFromApi}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).